# Why has google seen this message "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" after searching my domain name?

Tags: search, connection-refused

[In searching result **google display my website**.But **after clicking the result** shown like this.**I have dropped a screen short**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFxa0.jpg)

Comment: It means your server is not accepting connections.

Comment: How many reason for server accepting connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your server is not accepting connections.

For example:

- The server is not running.
- A firewall is blocking it.
- The domain name is not resolving to the host you want it to.
- You're trying to connect to your own host via its external IP address.